# Parse string representation of time values to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, parsing, format, timespan

I have an XML-File that contains multiple Attributes, that contains time values and I need to sum these values up.

```
<test>
   <value time="0.345"/>
   <value time="0.756"/>
   <value time="0.455"/>
</test>
```

But the problem is that `TimeSpan.Parse("0.345")` does not parse the value and results in an Exception. Event using `TimeSpan.Parse("0.345",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"))` results in the exception.

```
Message
Die Zeichenfolge wurde nicht als gültiger TimeSpan erkannt. 

StackTrace
   bei System.Globalization.TimeSpanParse.TimeSpanResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName)
   bei System.Globalization.TimeSpanParse.ProcessTerminal_HM(TimeSpanRawInfo& raw, TimeSpanStandardStyles style, TimeSpanResult& result)
   bei System.Globalization.TimeSpanParse.ProcessTerminalState(TimeSpanRawInfo& raw, TimeSpanStandardStyles style, TimeSpanResult& result)
   bei System.Globalization.TimeSpanParse.TryParseTimeSpan(String input, TimeSpanStandardStyles style, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TimeSpanResult& result)
   bei System.TimeSpan.Parse(String s)
```

So whats the correct ways to parse these time values to TimeSpan, so i can sum these values up?

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: what is 0.345 ? minutes? seconds?

Comment: you need to specify what units that time attribute is in? 0.345s, 0.345h or what??

Comment: @faby that are fractional/milliseconds seconds. 0 Seconds 345 Milliseconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what 1 means for you, one hour, minute, second, day, year ....

Presuming it means hour:

```
decimal hourFraction = decimal.Parse("0.345", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
long ticks = (long)(hourFraction * TimeSpan.FromHours(1).Ticks);
TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(ticks); // approximately 20 minutes
```

Once you have all `TimeSpan` values(f.e. in a `List<TimeSpan>`) you can use `Enumerable.Sum`:

```
TimeSpan sumDuration = new TimeSpan(allDurations.Sum(t => t.Ticks));
```

Answer (score 2):

try in this way with `TimeSpan.FromSeconds`

```
   var x=@"<root>
            <value time=""0.345""/>
            <value time=""0.756""/>
            <value time=""0.455""/>
        </root>";

   TextReader tr = new StringReader(x);
   var doc = XDocument.Load(tr);
   var timeSpanResult = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(doc.Descendants("value").Sum(
                y =>
                {
                    double value;
                    if (double.TryParse(y.Attribute("time").Value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value))
                    {
                        return value;
                    }
                    return 0;
                }));
```

I am assuming that values are all fractional seconds.
At the end your `timeSpanResult` variable will store the correct value

Answer (score 2):

*Well*, you can't parse this value with `TimeSpan.Parse` method.

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783872%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

```
[ws][-]{ d | [d.]hh:mm[:ss[.ff]] }[ws]
```

> Elements in square brackets (`[` and `]`) are optional. One selection from
>   the list of alternatives enclosed in braces (`{` and `}`) and separated by
>   vertical bars (`|`) is required.

As you can see, you don't have the hour and minutes part required. That's why you get [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.formatexception.aspx).

One solution could be concatenation your string values with `"0:0:"` to get strings like `"0:0:0.345"` which can be parsed successfully.

```
TimeSpan.Parse("0:0:0.345", new CultureInfo("de-DE")); // 00:00:00.3450000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only seconds, use TimeSpan.FromSeconds

EDIT: for string in op:

```
 string s = "0.455"
 var span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(s))
```

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` needs a `double`. I have a `string` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the value as double and use [TimeSpan.FromSeconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.timespan.fromseconds%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.